# Proof of the interpolation inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega \subseteq R^{n}$ be a bounded domain. I need to prove that for $u\in H^{2}(\Omega)\cap H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)$: 
\begin{equation}
\|\nabla u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}\leq \|u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}\|\Delta u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}
\end{equation}
I know that I should prove it for $u\in C^{2}_{0}(\Omega)$ and then use the Global Approximation Theorem with smooth functions to extend $u\in C^{2}_{0}(\Omega)$ to $u\in H^{2}(\Omega)\cap H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)$. Also, I know the following expression could be useful: 
\begin{equation}
\Delta(\frac{u^{2}}{2})=|\nabla u|^{2}+u\Delta u   
\end{equation}
I would appreciate a little help in this, I don't really have an idea to get started.

Comment: It is just integration by parts and cauchy schwarz.

Comment: To which function I should apply integration bu parts specifically?

Comment: $\int |\nabla u|^2=\int \nabla u \cdot \nabla u=\int u \Delta u$ + boundary terms; its the standard green formula.